# WPF changes the Resolution and scaling of the owner window

Tags: wpf, com, class-library, catia

I am currently creating a class library using C#. This library will be referenced using VBA in a win32 application CATIA. In the C# Solution, I have also a WPF project. Whenever I am calling a WPF UI in the class library, the scaling and resolution of CATIA changes to the DPI of the monitor. Its not the case with winForms as CATIA resolution does not change when I do a `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`.

I have tried a few things, like adding a manifest file and changing the dpiaware to false and dpiAwareness to unaware. but it does not seem to fix it.

Another thing that I have also noticed is that, If I call any method within the WPF Project from the main method, as long as it does not have `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` methods in it, the resolution remains same. So I know its not the fault of the WPF Project, but that of the window.

I have tried to add a manifest file and change the DPI settings manually, but they do not seem to work.

Comment: Hi DPI behavior is by default defined by the application, not the libraries it loads, so using manifest won't work if your code is hosted by some Catia exe (unless you tweak the whole Catia behavior which is probably not what you want to do). Office-hosted components face the same kind of issues so reading the related articles is probably interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution I would use `SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext` API before showing UI. Or ask Catia reps what's the recommended way.